# Android Facebook Graph Dialog content are not fully visible

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After lots of googling, I could not find any solution of my problem.
The Facebook dialog with Graph APi is not completely visible in small resolution's device.Few days back, it was fine but toady I don't know what changes Facebook team has done...

[image]

**In above image Login button is getting cropped from right side.**

[image]

**In above image buttons are very less visible and layout is not scroll able.**

Comment: this is not a code problem, this should be posted in android enthusiasts maybe... I guess that this is not your project apk, right?

Comment: @Fishonthegrass I have implemented Graph Api in my project.And It was runnig fine for last 6 months but today I found this problm

Comment: did you checked layout (if it is possible)?

Comment: @Fishonthegrass it is not possible

Comment: please file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs